# two sorted array and find k'th smallest number

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures

two sorted array `A, B` with length `n,m` `(n <= m)`, and `k` which `(k >= log n)` is given.

with `log (nm)` we can find `k-th` smallest number in union of these two array.

I have a solution In problem 2 [here](https://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/%7Emlampis/Algo/td4-sol.pdf), but my challenge is why two given condition "(n <= m)" and "k >= log n" does not affect this algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First assumption: `n <= m` is an assumption "without loss of generality". If n >= m, then just swap A and B in your head. They included this assumption even though it was not needed, because they felt it was "free" to make this assumption.
- Second assumption: A trivial algorithm to find the `k`th smallest element is to iterate over A and B simultaneously, advancing in the array that has the smaller element of the two. This would be exactly like running the "Merge" function from mergesort, but stopping once you've merged the first k elements. The complexity would be O(k). They wanted you to find a more complex algorithm, so they "ruled out" this algorithm by stating that k >= log(n), which implies that complexity O(k) is never better than O(log(n)). Technically, if they wanted to thoroughly rule this algorithm out, they should also have stated that `k <= n + m - log(n)`, otherwise you could run the "merge" function from the end: merge the n+m-k largest elements, then return the `n+m-k`th largest element, which is the same as the kth smallest element.

Comment: @user355834 Yes, the link you gave answers the question correctly. The first assumption does not affect anything. The second assumption does not affect anything if your goal is to find an O(log(nm)) solution, but does affect the question "What is better, O(k) or O(log(n))?"

Comment: @user355834 The answer is yes to all. The first equality is easy: log(mn) = log(m) + log(n), so the two sets O(log m + log n) and O(log(mn)) are of course equal. The second equality is not obvious. Equality of sets can be shown by showing the inclusing of the first set into the second set, and the inclusion of the second set into the first set. One of the inclusions is easy, but the other is harder. log(m+n) < log(mn), so the set O(log(m+n)) is of course included in the set O(log(mn)). The last inclusion is a bit trickier.

Comment: mn is in general much larger than m+n, so for an increasing function f that goes to infinity, there is usually no reason to expect that O(f(mn)) will be included in O(f(m+n)). In fact for most functions f, that would be false. However, log is a "very slow" function that tends to mash things together. For instance, n² or n³ or n⁴ are all much much bigger than n, but log(n⁴) = 4 log(n), so O(log(n⁴) and O(log(n)) are actually the same set.

Comment: please clean comments here.

Comment: Why? You don't like my comments :(

Comment: No for clear and nice question answer. just a tips.